# Reshape from wide to long format then summarizing it

Tags: r

Reshape from wide to long format

```
Diasorin %>%
pivot_longer(
everything(),
names_to = c("ID", "ID"),
names_pattern = "(.)()"
)
```

```
g2 <- function(x)
{round(c(MEAN=mean(x,na.rm=TRUE),MEDIAN=median(x,na.rm=TRUE),
MIN=min(x,na.rm=TRUE),MAX=max(x,na.rm=TRUE),
CV=100*sd(x)/mean(x),SD=sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)),1)}
```

```
summarize(value, by=low, FUN=g2)
```

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': object 'value' not found

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You are calling `summarize(value, by=low, FUN=g2)` but `value` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.